# "Epitaph" word puzzle from a joke book from 1800

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

This text comes from an old joke book from 1800, called *The New Jolly Jester Or Wit's Pocket Companion* (page 24). It appears to be some kind of word puzzle, or pun, perhaps along the lines of "URYY4me" ("you are too wise for me"), but I can't make it out at all, except that "I: won: Tu: B: E: C:" might conceivably mean "I want to be easy".

Can anyone decipher this please?

[image: An Epitaph]

Transcription follows:

An Epitaph

T: I: W.

--on--

K: I: won: Tu: B: E: C.

No os T. H. G: V: oh T: I.

T. I.

We: H: S: S: G. Ni: H: T. L. L

Ad.

Nat: Se: Ja: Se: Fil.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you read the text

> backwards,

you get:

> Life's a jest and all things shew it:
>  I thovght so once but now I know it.

Comment: This is in fact poet John Gay's "My Own Epitaph" (and it is indeed his own epitaph, on his monument in Westminster Abbey).

Answer (score 3):

> Haven't go all of it, but much is written backwards: WIT noce? but now I thought soon it'll? things shew da? life's a jest AN?

Comment: Thinking along the same lines. +1.